# Is there a word for wordlessly humming words/phrases?

Tags: single-word-requests, intonation

"Yeah-huh", "Nuh-uh".  "Ah."  "Oh."  "Um."   "Ew."  "Huh!"  "Huh?"  "Ehh." "I don't know."

Tone and breath are all that separate all of these 'm' sounds.  You can say a lot without opening your mouth.  Does this phenomenon have a name?

Comment: The word "humming" you used is good.

Comment: To many people "Ah", "Ew" and "Huh!" cannot be said with their mouth shut. Could you be clearer as to what noises you are actually referring to?

Comment: Agreed, duplicate.  I wish I had found that one, and I promise, I looked!

Answer (score 0):

Those are [interjections:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interjection)

> a cry or inarticulate utterance (such as Alas! ouch! phooey! ugh!) expressing an emotion.

(M-W)

Comment: I wonder if there's a better word since these utterances, while inarticulate, are perfectly suited to communicating information completely unemotionally as well, and (M-W seem to think that) an interjection is an emotional outburst.

Comment: @MmmmMmmm - irrespective of the emotional degree they may or may not convey,  I still think they are interjections.